# How do I fix this AWS bucket policy error?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to give a group access to an S3 bucket and writing the policy. I'm getting an "Invalid Principal Format" error with the principal, which I am setting to the group's ARN:

```
       {
            "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::1234566789:group/mygroup",
            "Sid": "writeAll",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:s3:::bucket",
               "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
            ]
        }
```

If I set the principal to "*", I don't get this error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify IAM group as a principal. [Valid principals](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html):

- AWS account and root user
- IAM roles
- Role sessions
- IAM users
- Federated user sessions
- AWS services
- All principals

Instead, you can create an IAM role, attach it to the IAM group, and specify the role as the principal in your S3 policy.

Alternatively, you can leave the idea of using an S3 bucket policy and create a regular IAM policy and attach it to the group:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per descriptions of principals [Principals Description](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html?opt_id=undefined), we cannot assign group to principals. Therefore, you can assign a custom policy to the group which allows only access to the buckets you have specified for the users in that group.